# Error while Overwrite CheckIn using Powershell

Tags: powershell, check-out, check-in

I got following error when I tried to Checkin files wich are Checked out by other users using powershell.

> Exception calling "CheckIn" with "2" argument(s): "You cannot checkin
>   and overwrite a published file."
>       At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Test2.ps1:71 char:13
>       +             $ListItems[$i].File.CheckIn("Checkin automatically",[Microsoft.Share ...

This is Powershell code:

```
 if($ListItems[$i].File.CheckOutStatus -ne "None")
 {
     $ListItems[$i].File.CheckIn("Checkin automatically",[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::OverwriteCheckIn)
 }
```

How I checkin files forcefully that are checked out by other users for a long time using powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Consider your current version of the file is 4.1 - you can check out this document and after you are done updating it you can check in with overwrite the draft (minor) version

But if you start with a published (major) version 4.0 and you check it out - then the overwrite check in is not possible

you can see this in the SharePoint UI as well - if you check out a published version of a document and immediately after that click the check in menu item - in the check-in page the overwrite check in option is missing.

Referred from [OverwriteCheckIn Not Working](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/dda8f456-902e-484c-9ed6-4cec7db9e035/overwritecheckin-not-working?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy)